# Firefox Extension - How to use preference for a menulist?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to use the tag `<preference>` for saving the state of a `<menulist>`. But I can't find out of what i'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
    <preferences>
        <preference id="selectpref1" name="preference.name" type="int" /> 
    </preferences>


    <menulist>
        <menupopup preference="selectpref1">
            <menuitem label="option 1" value="1"/>
            <menuitem label="option 2" value="2"/>
            <menuitem label="option 3" value="3"/>
            <menuitem label="option 4" value="4"/>
        </menupopup>
   </menulist>
```

Comment: The preference attribute should be on the menulist. One of your answers shows it placed correctly, although they erroneously thought that it was a different attribute that was the problem.

Comment: I think you marked wrong answer as correct. You were able to get this working with putting preference on menulist, correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that. You just need to add an oncommand to each of the menuitems, which changes the preference. You might also want to add a listener for the "popupshowing" event, which checks the preference and puts a checkmark by whichever one is currently selected.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences

Comment: Do you know how can I store Preference Values using JavaScript?

Comment: Updated my answer. The "code snippets" page is always quite helpful.

Comment: You can actually do that. According to the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preferences_system/New_attributes
```By default, the <preference> element will automatically modify the value of a few standard widgets: checkbox, colorpicker, radiogroup, textbox, listitem, listbox, and menulist.```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, here's code from my extension:

```
<hbox align="center">
    <label value="Log Level" control="loglevellist" />
    <menulist id="loglevellist" preference="loglevel" preference-editable="true">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="Full" value="0" />
        <menuitem label="Relevant" value ="1" />
        <menuitem label="Warning" value="2" />
        <menuitem label="Error" value="3" />
        <menuitem label="Critical" value="4" />
      </menupopup>
    </menulist>
  </hbox>
```

loglevel preference is integer. <strike>Basically I think you're only missing **preference-editable** attribute</strike>

**EDIT:**
 I didn't see properly, you had preference attribute on *menupopup* instead on **menulist** - preference should go on menulist.

Comment: It Worked!! I was Also using the prefence atribute on the menupopup.

Comment: The preference-editable attribute already defaults to true on checkbox, colorpicker, radiogroup, textbox, listitem, listbox and menulist elements.

Comment: You're correct Neil, it was on menulist not on menupopup that preference should go. I thought he had preference on menulist, so I assumed he was missing preference-editable. I'll correct my answer so.